# What are Redis options object key titles for KEEPTTL & XX (update if present)?

Tags: javascript, redis

I have updated my Redis verison to "^4.2.0" in Node and I have to convert my old client.set methods to use the options object instead of comma separated options.

I have been able to do this with setting a value because the documentation says the key titles for expiring is "EX" like...

```
const setValue = async (key, value, exp) => {
   await client.set(key, JSON.stringify(value), { EX: exp }) 
}
```

But what are the options object key titles for "KEEPTTL" & "XX" (update if present)???
See question marks below...

```
const updateValue = async (key, value) => {
   await client.set(key, JSON.stringify(value), { <?>: "KEEPTTL", <?>: "XX" })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XX` means only set the key, if the key already exists, i.e. do not add a new key.

`KEEPTTL` is a new option Redis 6.0. By default, when you call `set key value` on a key, the expiration time (TTL) will be reset, i.e. no TTL any more. However, with this option, you can only change the value, without modifying the TTL.